# strange behaviour while iterating through c++ map

Tags: c++, loops, dictionary, size

I have the following program which finds the frequency of the numbers.

```
map<int,int> mp;
vector<int> x(4);
x[0] = x[2] = x[3] = 6;
x[1] = 8;

for(int i=0;i<x.size();++i)
    mp[x[i]]++;

cout<<"size:"<<mp.size()<<endl; //Prints 2 as expected

for(int i=0;i<mp.size();++i) //iterates from 0->8 inclusive
    cout<<i<<":"<<mp[i]<<endl;
```

The output is as follows:

```
size:2
0:0
1:0
2:0
3:0
4:0
5:0
6:3
7:0
8:1
```

Why does it iterate over 9 times? I also tried using `insert` instead of `[]` operator while inserting elements, but the result is the same. I also tested by iterating over the map using iterator.

Comment: `mp[i]` will add a new element if one doesn't already exist, you are adding to the map while attempting to loop over it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before your printing loop, the populated `mp` elements are `[6]` and `[8]`.  When you call `cout ... << mp[i]` to print with `i` `0`, it inserts a new element `[0]` with the default value `0`, returning a reference to that element which then gets printed, then your loop test `i < mp.size()` actually compares against the new size of `3`.  Other iterations add further elements.

You should actually do:

```
for (std::map<int,int>::const_iterator i = std::begin(mp);
     i != std::end(mp); ++i)
    std::cout << i->first << ':' << i->second << '\n';
```

...or, for C++11...

```
for (auto& e : mp)
    std::cout << e.first << ':' << e.second << '\n';
```

Answer (score 1):

When you access `mp[i]`, the element is added to the map if it doesn't already exist. So the first iteration of the loop will attemp to read `mp[0]`. This will create the element, so now `mp.size() == 3`. The size will continue to increase whenever an iteration attempts to access an element that doesn't exist.

When you get to `i == 8`, the element exists, so it doesn't increase the size. When it gets back to the top of the loop and tests `9 < mp.size()`, it will fail and the loop ends.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you use `mp[i]` in the printing loop you *create* those items that doesn't exist in the map.

Use iterators instead,